# How is the R generic type in ReadWriteProperty expected to be used?

Tags: generics, kotlin

How is the `R` generic type expected to be used? Everywhere I see `ReadWriteProperty` implemented, `R` is defined as either `Any` or `Any?` and then the two parts of the implementation that use type `R` (named `thisRef` below) are never used.

Kotlin's `ReadWriteProperty` is defined as the following (code was copy/pasted from a source file):

```
/**
 * Base interface that can be used for implementing property delegates of read-write properties.
 *
 * This is provided only for convenience; you don't have to extend this interface
 * as long as your property delegate has methods with the same signatures.
 *
 * @param R the type of object which owns the delegated property.
 * @param T the type of the property value.
 */
public interface ReadWriteProperty<in R, T> {
    /**
     * Returns the value of the property for the given object.
     * @param thisRef the object for which the value is requested.
     * @param property the metadata for the property.
     * @return the property value.
     */
    public operator fun getValue(thisRef: R, property: KProperty<*>): T

    /**
     * Sets the value of the property for the given object.
     * @param thisRef the object for which the value is requested.
     * @param property the metadata for the property.
     * @param value the value to set.
     */
    public operator fun setValue(thisRef: R, property: KProperty<*>, value: T)
}
```

Comment: You can make a delegate property that targets a specific type of receiver. It would only be usable within that class and it’s subclasses, but you would have access to its functions and properties.

Comment: @Tenfour04 are you able to provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a delegate property that targets a specific type of receiver. It would only be usable within that class and it’s subclasses, but you would have access to its functions and properties.

As an example, you could make a class that counts calls to any of its properties that use the delegate:

```
open class Ticker {
    var ticks = 0
        private set

    class CountedAccess<T> (private val value: T) : ReadOnlyProperty<Ticker, T> {
        override fun getValue(thisRef: Ticker, property: KProperty<*>): T {
            thisRef.ticks++
            return value
        }
    }
}
```

Then a subclass would be tracking number of calls to any of its delegated properties:

```
fun main() {
    class Something: Ticker() {
        val foos by CountedAccess(5)
        val bar by CountedAccess("Hello, world!")
    }

    val something = Something().apply {
        repeat(Random.nextInt(3)) {
            println("Number of foos is $foos")
            repeat(Random.nextInt(3)) {
                println("Bar says $bar")
            }
        }
    }
    println("Something's properties were accessed ${something.ticks} times.")
}
```